# Use of collections to describe pedestrians location at PedSource

Tags: anylogic

*Benjamin, thanks for your reply.  I really appreciate your answer because you know how desperate one gets when one has no idea what to try.*

I did it using the suggestion to select the nodes and right-click, create **collection.** I must be forgetting something because it didn't work for me.

**[COLLECTION DEFINITION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncxyq.jpg)**

Let's see if I'm understanding, in the Anylogic example, *they use it to create pedestrians on the train platform, at the 32 doors*.

***I want to use that tool to avoid having to make a programming line for each room (cr) to evacuate pedestrians to a safe point.***

I include the screenshot of the **PedSource**. I'm looking at what the **light bulb** has... so I should start with **self or ped**. But, the Anylogic model has no self and no ped. Any additional ideas?

[**New PedSource**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfYBH.jpg)

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

I have been studying several of Anylogic's examples. In this case, the **"Subway Platform".**
**[SUBWAY PLATFORM LOGIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zzkh.jpg)**

Anylogic uses a **collection** of doors to simulate the train doors where pedestrians will appear, using target lines. In the **PedSource**, they describe it as Target Line: **doors1.get(index)**
[SP PEDSOURCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyR7g.jpg)

I want to achieve the same thing using nodes. My **collection** is called **cr_Ele** and I have written in the **Ped Source** > Node: **cr_Ele.get(index).**
[My COLLECTION OF NODES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJo5Z.jpg)
[MY PEDSOURCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2GSO.jpg)

Running it gives me the following error, "index cannot be resolved to a variable". Does anyone have any idea what might be causing the error?

This is my first question on this platform, I hope I did it right!

Answer (score 0):

great question, well done :)

The problem is that your collection is defined as a group of `Object` elements, see your "Element class" entry. Compare to what AnyLogic did: Their element class is set to "Other" specifying the actual type:
[image]

You can do the same thing. Easiest is to select several of your nodes, right-click, select "Create collection". This will give you this collection:
[image]

Alternatively, you can use code-complete and learn the object types from the API.

Now, you can access individual `PolygonalNode` elements from your collection using `myCollection.get(0)´ (or any other index)